# Merge the rows of a df based on contiguous values of a particular column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, search

I have a df like this:

```
    text    labels
0   2083    [CARDINAL (0.8677)]
1   2085    [CARDINAL (0.5846)]
2   1822    [DATE (0.9581)]
3   DHAKA.  [GPE (0.6306)]
4   BANGLADESH  [GPE (0.6535)]
5   2085    [CARDINAL (0.7502)]
6   Manlkganj   [GPE (0.8888)]
7   Bangladesh  [GPE (0.9916)]
```

What I want is:

```
        text              labels
0   2083, 2085           CARDINAL
1   1822                  DATE
2   DHAKA. BANGLADESH      GPE
3   2085                 CARDINAL
4   Manlkganj Bangladesh    GPE
```

Club the contious values of same labels and merge them and make it one row and drop every other row which is not in `ls=['GPE', 'ORG', 'CARDINAL']`.

I have done it in a more non-pythonic way, looping over the df with df.iterrows() and then df['labels'].str.split('('][0] in ls, takes a lot of time and not getting the proper desired results as well. I was wondering if there's a way to do it more efficiently, a string operation and manipulation of rows.

df to dict 'dict' format to recreate:

```
{'text': {0: '2083',
  1: '2085',
  2: '1822',
  3: 'DHAKA.',
  4: 'BANGLADESH',
  5: '2085',
  6: 'Manlkganj',
  7: 'Bangladesh',
  8: 'DHAKA',
  9: 'BANGLADESH'},
 'start_pos': {0: 49,
  1: 54,
  2: 107,
  3: 236,
  4: 243,
  5: 355,
  6: 396,
  7: 414,
  8: 540,
  9: 547},
 'end_pos': {0: 53,
  1: 58,
  2: 111,
  3: 242,
  4: 253,
  5: 359,
  6: 405,
  7: 424,
  8: 545,
  9: 557},
 'labels': {0: [CARDINAL (0.8677)],
  1: [CARDINAL (0.5846)],
  2: [DATE (0.9581)],
  3: [GPE (0.6306)],
  4: [GPE (0.6535)],
  5: [CARDINAL (0.7502)],
  6: [GPE (0.8888)],
  7: [GPE (0.9916)],
  8: [GPE (0.5669)],
  9: [GPE (0.878)]}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start with `df.labels = df.labels.apply(lambda x: x.split(' (')[0][1:])` to transform the labels column.

Comment: Your `labels` column seem to contain lists of (one) object. What are `CARDINAL/DATE/GPE`?

Comment: Entities. Yes, list with one item. @QuangHoang

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```py
df.labels = df.labels.apply(lambda x: x[0].split()[0])
```

*Note*: if you have a large DataFrame, you're better to figure out how to use `df.explode('labels')` instead.
and then use

```py
g = (df.labels != df.shift().fillna(method='bfill').labels).cumsum().rename('group')
df.groupby(['labels',g]).agg({'text': ', '.join})
```

Reworked from here: [Python/Pandas: Merging Consecutive Rows Only if Matching Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373668/python-pandas-merging-consecutive-rows-only-if-matching-columns)

And here: [Concatenate strings from several rows using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: This coming up with: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: What is the `type` in the labels column? Is it a `list`, or a `string`?

Comment: pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: It is not producing the end dataframe which I'm trying to construct. Thank you for your help.